# Swift object values gets printed to the table view but shows as empty when printed to console

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, realm

I have created a class as below:

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class StockCellContent: Object{

    @objc dynamic var StockName: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var image: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var requiredStockPrice: Double = 0.0000
    @objc dynamic var requiredPriceUpOrDown: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var StockPrice: Double = 0.0000
    //var parentCategory = LinkingObjects(fromType: Category.self, property: "StockCellContent")

}
```

then i have created a object of that class and called a function which gets the data through an api and saves it in the object. Then i add the object to an array to be printed on the `UITableView`.
The `UITableView` prints the values perfectly fine but when i try to pass the same object anywhere else or even print it to the console the data becomes nil or the default value with which it has been initialised. I don't understand what i am doing wrong here.

the function is as below:

```
func dataReceived(data: String) {
    self.stockNames.append(data)
    self.stockKeyword = data
    //var stockData = StockCellContent()
    //var stockDataTest = StockObjectTest()
    let params = ["function" : "GLOBAL_QUOTE", "symbol" : stockKeyword, "apikey" : stockApiKey]
    let stockData = getStockPriceFromJSON(url: stockApiURL, parameters: params)
    //print(stockData.StockPrice)

    print(stockData.StockPrice)
    self.stockArray.append(stockData)

    //print(data)
    //print(stockData.StockName)
    //print(stockData.StockPrice)
    //print(self.stockArray[0].StockPrice)
    //self.stockCellContents = stockData
    //self.stockList.append(newCategory)
    self.save(stockCellContent: stockData)

    self.stockUpdateFlag = true
    //updateTable()
    //tableView.reloadData()
}
```

The print of `stockData.StockPrice` shows `0.0`
even `stockData.StockName` shows empty

Comment: Is `getStockPriceFromJSON` async? If so, maybe you should fill  `stockData` inside its closure after the response has received.

Comment: Please see [Returning data from async call in Swift function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203556/returning-data-from-async-call-in-swift-function?r=SearchResults&s=1|67.3104)

Comment: No. It's not async. And honestly, I do not know how to make it even if I wanted to.

Comment: Have you looked in the debugger? Is it possible that your assumption "The UITableView prints the values perfectly fine" is somehow wrong (using default values or getting the values from someplace else)? Have you checked the getStockPriceFromJSON (for example by intentionally crashing it, if the value is correct)?

Comment: Please add `getStockPriceFromJSON`. Most likely it is indeed asynchronous.

Comment: I figured out the problem. The getStockPriceFromJSON method which tries to get the data from the api takes too long to return the data and the rest of the code is been executed even before the data is returned and set to the object variable. So the method was returning the empty first and then the data was then getting set. I realised it when i tried to print two tests in the if else case inside alamofire closure and just before the return statement. The line before the return statement got executed first and then the one which was inside the if else.

Comment: This still did not explain how the table view used to get the data properly. The default valued were 0, prior to me setting it.